# java/android - Can I edit phone mechanics with java instead of just apps?

Tags: java, android

I've been wondering, since you can make apps and such using the ADK and JDK, is there a way to change certain mechanics on the phone itself aswell?? like themes, actions when starting apps, calls, the browser, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. Most of the actions you describe are executed as "root" user, which has access to EVERYTHING on your phone, while (normal) apps are executed as user, which lacks those rights. There are exceptions to this in the form of apps that run as "root", but these require you to go through a process that is aptly named "rooting your phone". This however is not recommended unless you know what you're doing.

Comment: is there a way I can learn rooting for phone apps? something thats explain it to me

Comment: Looking on the web will give you results on how to do this, but I strongly recommend NOT doing it. Doing something wrong can result in you "bricking" your phone. This means your phone is not working anymore and in some cases might not be restoreable. What is the reason you want to get root access anyway?

Comment: I see, and I wanna get into phone development ontop of making apps for ultimate customization

Comment: If you want to get into phone development, try creating apps that dont require root access and basically just make use of the systems native solution by functioning as a wrapper.

Comment: a wrapper ,like?  background type tool?

Comment: A wrapper as in: it looks like an app and you can customize what is where, but every function simply calls the required functions from the native system. Basically you can flip your call sign upside down and require your user to draw a dinosaur on the screen, but once that is completed the function simply calls on the systems native method that handles calling the assigned telephone.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is the creation of a custom ROM. Taking the original source code, modifying it, and then packaging it so it can be installed on another phone.

This is a very difficult and complex task, especially when you want your modification to be available on different phones. They all have unique specificities and most likely will need specific versions of your mod.